# I need to view my windows credentials password

Tags: powershell, encryption, passwords, credentials, decryption

I lost a password ,but it is saved under windows credentials. It will log me in to certain apps but if it's something I haven't logged into yet it won't. I have a .crd file ,which I got by backing up the credentials in the control panel. Can I access the file and the passwords in it? I have tried so many things to get into the file/credentials but I am lost at this point. Please help. Thank you.

Edit: One of the most promising things I did was access the web credentials through the powershell ,but I couldn't access the windows credentials. Idk if it matters but thought I'd mention it

Answer (score 3):

Sorry man.  You are not going to be successful.  Your password is not stored like you think.  Only a hash of it is stored in a SAM file.  The credentials file you have doesn't contain any local passwords like you hope.

Credential files (CRD) only contain:

- Login passwords of remote computers on your LAN.
- Passwords of mail accounts on exchange server (stored by Microsoft Outlook)
- Windows Live session information.
- Remote Desktop 6 user\password information.
- Internet Explorer 7.x and 8.x: passwords of password-protected Web sites ("Basic Authentication" or "Digest Access Authentication")
- Password of MSN Messenger / Windows Messenger accounts

You might try googling ***windows 10 password reset*** .. I have used many methods to do it for previous versions of Windows.  I haven't ever done it for Windows 10 so I can't give you advice that I know works.

Perhaps someone else will come along and prove me wrong (I hope).. but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

But.. but...but.., we are here to help you with non-working PowerShell code. which this is not. This is of course and user environment issue.

What did you search for?

The tool in Control Panel is called WIndwos Credential Manager and unless you cleared this, then all that is still there.

There are modules that allow you to interact with the 'Windows Credential Manager'.

```
Find-Module -Name '*credential*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Version        Name                          Repository Description                                                                                            
-------        ----                          ---------- -----------                                                                                            
2.0            CredentialManager             PSGallery  Provides access to credentials in the Windows Credential Manager                                       
1.0.4          WindowsCredential             PSGallery  Management module for Windows Credential Store.                                                        
1.1.0          CredentialSpec                PSGallery  Tools to create and find Credential Spec files used to run Windows Server Containers with Active Dir...
...
1.0.11         pscredentialmanager           PSGallery  This module allows management and automation of Windows cached credentials.                            
...
1.0.0          CredentialLocker              PSGallery  CredentialLocker is a module that provides commandlets to manage credentials in the password vault.... 
...
1.0.2          CredentialManagement          PSGallery  Manage Credentials stored in the Windows Credential Manager                                            
...
#>

Find-Module -Name CredentialManager | 
Save-Module -Name CredentialManager "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules"
Install-Module -Name CredentialManager

Import-module -Name CredentialManager

Get-Command -Module CredentialManager | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
CommandType Name                    Version Source           
----------- ----                    ------- ------           
Cmdlet      Get-StoredCredential    2.0     CredentialManager
Cmdlet      Get-StrongPassword      2.0     CredentialManager
Cmdlet      New-StoredCredential    2.0     CredentialManager
Cmdlet      Remove-StoredCredential 2.0     CredentialManager
#>
```

Comment: How that solves the question? Just need to run it and gives you the password?